# Convert apache rewrite rules to lighttpd rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, lighttpd

How to convert this Apache rewrite rules to lighttpd rules?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this one will work .

```
url.rewrite-once = (
".*\?(.*)$" => "/index.php?$1",
".*\.(?i)(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|css|html)$" => "$0",
"" => "/index.php")
```